# Overloading struct operator loses precision when multiplying doubles

Tags: c++

I have a `Point3d` class for which I created a scalar multiplication operator like so:

```
Point3d operator*(double mul) { return {x*mul, y*mul, z*mul}; }
```

This does not seem to multiply doubles correctly. In my testing when I multiply a `Point3d` object by `10^-6` and then check the `x` coordinate, I get `.000002`.

But, when multiplying the components by hand I get `2.1584e-06`.

The former definitely only has 1 digit of precision because if the operator is too small the `Point3d` goes to `0.0`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you explain how the linked question is related to my issue?

Comment: I don't believe it is related myself, which is why I voted to re-open :-) This is less of a floating point limited-precision issue and more of a *printing* issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write them both out *without* an exponent, you see:

```
.000002
.0000021584
```

That means they're equal, to the point where the former stops. So it's almost certainly the *printing* of the value that's giving you your difference. Try it with something like:

```
#include <cstdio>
:
printf("%.20f\n", myDouble); // I can't be bothered looking up the iomanp stuff :-)
```

This should show you more than the default number of digits.

Comment: Thanks this solves my problem, I was printing with to_string(x) in one instance and cout << x  in the other.

Comment: That's what I was going to say.